# Download apk file. Work fine on AVD but on real phone dasn't

Tags: android, download, apk, android-virtual-device

Hello i am trying to download apk file from web server to my android application (/download) dir.
The problem is: on AVD is working fine but on my real phone S2 do not download this apk file.
Please hellp :)

the code:`

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_update_apk);

    BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {

                //  openFile();

            }
        }
    };

    registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(
            DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));


    /*
    //del old file
    File fileUpdate = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)+"/"+fileName);
    if(fileUpdate != null){
        fileUpdate.delete();
    }*/

    startDownload();
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void startDownload() {
    try{
        dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Request request = new Request(
                Uri.parse("http://10.10.10.10/andr_test/download_new_version/appUpdate.apk"));
        enqueue = dm.enqueue(request);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Can't download file", "Can't download file-" + e.getMessage());
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

The host:10.10.10.10 is a real host that your real phone network can access? Or just a test host only can accessed by your desktop.

Comment: phone can access the address. when i write the address in the browser phone start to download the file